# How to view results in a file using a function and *apply?

Tags: r, apply

I like to pop out results in a window so that they're easier to see and find (e.g., they don't get lost as the console continues to scroll).  One way to do this is to use `sink()` and `file.show()`.  For example:

```
y <- rnorm(100); x <- rnorm(100); mod <- lm(y~x)
sink("tempSink", type="output")
summary(mod)
sink()
file.show("tempSink", delete.file=T, title="Model summary")
```

I commonly do this to examine model fits, as above, but also for a wide variety of other functions and objects, such as: `summary(data.frame)`, `anova(model1, model2)`, `table(factor1, factor2)`.  These are common, but other situations can arise as well.  The point here is that both the nature of the function and the object can vary.

It is somewhat tedious to type out all of the above every time.  I would like to write a simpler function that I can call, something like the following would be nice:

```
sinkShow <- function(obj, fun, title="output") {
    sink("tempSink", type="output")
    apply(obj, ?, fun)
    sink()
    file.show("tempSink", delete.file=T, title=title)
}
```

Clearly, this doesn't work.  There are several issues.  First, how would you do this so that it won't crash with the wrong type of object or function without having to have a list of conditional executions (i.e., `if(is.list(obj) { lapply...`).  Second, I'm not sure how to handle the `margin` argument.  Lastly, this doesn't work even when I try simple, contrived examples where I know that everything is set appropriately, so there seems to be something fundamentally wrong.

Does anyone know how such a situation can be handled simply and easily?  I'm not new to R, but I've never been formally taught it; I've picked up tricks in an ad-hoc manner, i.e., I'm not a very sophisticated R programmer.  Thanks.

Comment: Look up S3 classes, which will likely be the easiest way to do what you want.  You can then `lapply` the generic function to a list of the objects you want to examine.

Comment: @gung: I took the liberty of editing the title to express more clearly the direction your question took.  Feel free to edit again or change back if you disagree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `page`.  Here's some sample models:

```
d <- data.frame(y1=rnorm(100), y2=rnorm(100), x=rnorm(100))
mod <- lm(y1~x, data=d)
mods <- list(mod1=lm(y1~x, data=d), mod2=lm(y2~x, data=d))
```

And here's how you'd use `page`:

```
page(summary(mod), method="print")
page(lapply(mods, summary), method="print")
```

For my original post, which had code that turned out to be a near-reimplementation of `page`, see the edit history.

Comment: Using "tempSink" probably won't mess anything up but it still might be safer to use `tempfile()` instead.

Comment: @gung: I just discovered `page` which is a base R function that does basically what my function did.  See edit for details.

Comment: That's great, Aaron, I don't need a function anymore. I didn't know of it before, but `page` does everything I want.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than use `apply` I think you want `do.call`.  Make sure to wrap it in a `print` since it is inside of a function.

Here is one possible implementation:

```
sinkShow <- function( obj, fun, title='Output', ...) {
    file <- tempfile()
    args <- c(list(obj),list(...))

    capture.output( do.call( fun, args ), file=file )
    file.show(file, delete.file=TRUE, title=title)
}
```

Though it should probably be renamed since I skipped using sink as well.  I might modify this a bit and put it into the TeachingDemos package.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's good to have more than one way to do it.

Comment: GregSnow and @baptiste: So your suggestion has gotten several votes, and while I'm not too keen on `eval` either, I don't see how to use `do.call` here in a straightforward way.  Would someone provide more details? Thanks.

Comment: I added a version of the function using do.call.

Comment: @GregSnow: I just discovered the `page` function, which we both basically reimplemented.  See edits to my post.